# How to do status with different icon button and navigate to different function in controller

Tags: sapui5

i'm trying to display the Status with different icon button and the icon can be press to call different function in controller. here is the code of how i display the different icon button based on Status. however, i'm having problem to navigate those buttons to different function.

```
<Button icon="{= (${TaskStatus} === 'OPEN') ? 'sap-icon://wrench' : 'sap-icon://accelerated' }"> </Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to create a [sap.m.Button](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Button) for each function and set the visibility based on your property 'TaskStatus'.

```
<Button icon="sap-icon://wrench" press="function1" visible="{= ${TaskStatus} === 'OPEN' }"/>
<Button icon="sap-icon://accelerated" press="function2" visible="{= !${TaskStatus} === 'OPEN' }"/>
```

By doing that you give 1 action to a specific Button which makes it, In my opinion, easier to read for possible future developers on your project.

Comment: hi. thanks for responding to my Question. i've tried your solution and it didnt work. since i need to put the icon in a table, so i think there should be only one button.

Comment: You didn't mention the button was placed in a table. If in a table, you could try to surround the 2 Buttons by a VBox. This is because each cell in a row only expects 1 control.

Comment: any time, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

xml:

```
<Button 
    id="idButton" 
    icon="{= (${TaskStatus} === 'OPEN') ? 'sap-icon://wrench' : 'sap-icon://accelerated' }"
    press="onButton"/>
```

controller:

```
onButton: function () {
    if ( this.getView().byId("idButton").getIcon() === "sap-icon://wrench" ) {
        this._functionA();
    } else if ( this.getView().byId("idButton").getIcon() === "sap-icon://accelerated" ) {
        this._functionB();
    } else {
        //some error handling
    }
},


_functionA: function() {
    //ur logic
}

_functionB: function() {
    //ur logic
}
```

reply to comment:
the getIcon works for me (tested the code in one of my projects):
[image]

Comment: hi. i've tried your solution but it didnt works for the controller. there is no error, it just when i clicked the icon, there is nothing happen. it seems like it couldnt read the icon from the view.

Comment: this is because, for eg, when i put this._functionA() in the else {  //some error handling }
 - part, all the icons can triggered the function successfully. so i guess there is something wrong for the part to to get the icon

Comment: https://ui5.sap.com/1.62.0/#/api/sap.m.Button/methods/getIcon  as you see it should work, have you tried to debug it and see what the getIcon() delivers? is should be URI of the icon meaning "sap-icon://..." maybe you have to call a toString or smth